# Broken images in media library

Tags: images, uploads, media-library

I have been trying to upload images to my WP media library, but for some reason they are all showing up as broken image icons. The  images I've uploaded previously are working fine, it's only when trying to add new images to the library.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to WPSE. I assume you installed a plugin or added some code to your theme that caused this issue. Can you add some more information please?

Comment: The weird part is I didnt add any plugins or touch the code, the issue began when months later I went to add more images to the site. I think the issue has to do with the image url path because the url for the image I'm uploading is "http://pinnacleconstructionpartners.com/wp-content/uploads/mattress_firm-1.jpg" and under settings where it says "store uploads in this folder" the path reads "/home/seasideframing1/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2016/02". However, after trying to add the image to the "uploads/2016/02" folder through godaddy hosting, it still isnt working.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue.  It miraculously went away when I unchecked the option to save media in year and month subdirectories.  Weird.